# how can I merge two files using specific column that have duplicate string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-processing

[image]

I have this to tables df1 and df2 and I want to merge this file using a column kebele_name using the similar value
for example df1 wosharba I want to search woshamba from df2 and merge the files and save to the new csv file

this was the code I used

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv("combined_csv2.csv")
csv2 = pd.read_csv("snnp.csv")
csv_out = csv1.merge(csv2, on=['woreda_name','kebele_name'])
csv_out.to_csv("file_out11.csv", index=False
```

but it says the kebele_name or woreda_name duplicate
I want to keep the delicate values as well

Comment: It would be helpful if you upload your current code trying to solve it, so that people can provide better solution what you want.

Comment: I am unclear of the error you receive. Can you post the fuller traceback, word for word, without your paraphrasing? It sounds like you have *other* same name columns. Please post `csv1.columns` and `csv2.columns`.

Comment: Aside - it is always a good practice to name files and objects with clear names denoting their content. `csv2` and `file_out11.csv` are not clear for reproducibility and maintainability. You will thank yourself when returning to old code and files few weeks/month/years from now.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file1.ext', 'r') as f1:
  data1 = f1.read()
with open('file2.ext', 'r') as f2:
  data2 = f2.read()
data_write = data1 + data2
with open ('final.ext', 'w') as file:
  file.write(data_write)
```

Hopefully this works :)

Comment: thank you for your fast replay, It works but did not take the other File values which are not available in the second file like Region, zone

Comment: @DestaWerash please show your Python code for this task

Comment: @DestaWerash instead of concatenation the 2 files try adding them to a list and merging the data like that. All it needs to do is add the data together either by appending it or concatenation. If you get me?